# Good methods to store numeric to any-type mappings in R

Tags: r, list, hash, dictionary

If one is interested in holding data in the form

```
numeric --> any_type
```

without resorting to casting, how should one go about it?

What is mean is, although this is illegal:

```
x<-list(1 = "one", 2 = "two");
```

the desired functionality / behaviour can be proxied with:

```
x<-list("1" = "one", "2" = "two");
```

and for retrieval of values,

```
x[as.character(1)]; # would produce the value "one"
```

This second method however requires explicit casts to character while constructing the list and while retrieving key value pairs.

I've taken a look at the package 'hash', but this doesn't resolve the issue either.

Comment: How would you propose to resolve the conflict between `x[1]` and `x[\`1\`]`?

Comment: What about doing `x <- list("one", "two")` and `x[[1]]` and `x[[2]]`? Or is the problem that your integers won't always be `1` and `2` but might be `28` and `42516789901`? In which case, you picked a bad example.

Comment: Are the values always of the same type? So your map could be a two column data.frame: `x <- data.frame(key = c(1, 2), value = c("one", "two"))`. To extract, you can do: `with(x, value[match(1, key)]`. And you can do more complex things with `merge`. This approach also gives you the possibility to map multiple keys to multiple values. Finally, using `data.table` will likely be faster and might use a simpler syntax.